# Trying to call http post from android - why is it not working?

Tags: android

The code :

```
private boolean callHttpPost()
{
boolean retVal = false; 

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try 
    {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } 
          catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
          {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } 
          catch (IOException e) 
          {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

I get to the IOException all the time i call this method - and i dont know why. 
The IOException e is empty - so i can't see actually what is the exception i get.

I checked with Fiddler application that this http/post work with those parameters - and its look ok

Comment: do you have internet permission in manifest?

Comment: did not add this permission :( - how to do it please ?

Comment: Add this line in manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> after the application tag close or before starts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<manifest 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-sdk ..
  <application...
  </application>
</manifest>
```